# Store HTML from Java in to MYSQL Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, escaping

I am trying to store some HTML created by users with TinyMCE .I am using JQuery AJAX POST to post content to other page . What happens is HTML is having `&nbsp;` or `&amp;` than it treats content after that as a new parameter so only content before that '&' is stored to database.Do I have to escape it before posting ?If so how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoopse .... escape() worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

I would never save HTML in a database.  HTML is presentation; relational databases are for persistence.  Save the data and format it as HTML.  Keep the two layers separate.

Comment: What if there is some application where user can have their own htm content?There is no predefined template in this case.

Comment: Wordpress or any other CMS? It is quite justified in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

the data must be stored in a database and the layout (html) in a webform or related. 
Retrieve the data when needed and add the html code in the page itself